# behavior bulleted list/code

Tags: bug

There is a weird behavior about code when write after Bulleted list.

Example :

**When Bulleted list is before code:**

- 1rst affirmation
- 2nd affirmation

  ```
  weird code really bad
  ```

  another code annoying
  closing example1

**When Bulleted list is after code:**

```
weird code really bad
another code annoying
closing example2
```

- 1rst affirmation
- 2nd affirmation

As you can see, code have got a weird behavior (just like a <kbd>Tab</kbd> done) when a bulleted list is write just before.

Check with the *Edit* if your aren't convinced, I see that when editing this following question :

[Dell latitude e6410 lagging (intel HD graphics)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052422/dell-latitude-e6410-lagging)

So how do you add code **after** bulleted list **without** saw a space as it can be inside the bulleted list?